# How to call Message App from My App?

Tags: iphone, sms

How to call Message App from my current app.
I know to use this code...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
@"sms:1-408-555-1212"]];
```

But what I want is just to call Message App, I don't want with phone no or without phone no.
Just want to open current Message App View.
Please help me....

Comment: Thanks for reply Jack.
but this one also need to select recipient info for every time when you want to send message.It may be troublesome for user.

Comment: Why launch the Messages app? Just use `MFMessageComposeViewController`. You can pre-populate it with recipients if needed as well as a message body.

Comment: Hi rmaddy,  Thanks for your reply. My idea is copy and paste the text.  and my text is not the normal font. so every time after user compose the text, copy it and call Message App and paste it.So user compose, copy, call and paste.I already finished compose copy with one click button. now what i need was to call SMS app with current view.

Answer (score 2):

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messagComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
            {
                messagComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self; 
                messagComposer.recipients = recipientsArray; // here give array of recipints
                messagComposer.body = @"Some text";
                [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];                    
             }
```

try like this for sending message

Comment: Don't forget to add `MessageUI.framework`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

Import **MessageUI** framework in project.

in .h file,

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

Calling Method forSending SMS : **`[self SendSMS:@"YOUR_MESSAGE" recipientList:ARRAY_OF_RECIPIENTS];`**

Here, it you don't have any recipient, then pass array as **`nil`**.

Method ::

```
- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    [controller release];
}
```

Message Framework Methods ::

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status:" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
           alert.message = @"Cancelled";

           break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
           alert.message = @"Failed";

           break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
           alert.message = @"Send";

           break;
        default:
           break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.